# Stack overflow while allocating from heap

Tags: c++, boost, stack, overflow

What exactly is happening here?

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

struct Toy {
    int m_data[100000];
};

struct Box {
    Box()
        : m_toys(  boost::assign::list_of( Toy() )( Toy() )( Toy() )  )
    {}

    boost::array<Toy,3>   m_toys;
};

void main()
{
    Box* box = new Box; // This causes stack overflow
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `Toy()` objects being passed to `boost::assign::list_of()`. These are temporary objects which are created on the stack before being copied to the `Box` object (which will be on the heap)

to avoid creating them on the stack, you could do this:

```
Box() : m_toys()
{
   Toy* t = new Toy;
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
       m_toys.push_back(*t);
   delete t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value

```
boost::assign::list_of( Toy() )( Toy() )( Toy() )
```

generates a (giant) temporary on the stack (woo!) that is passed to the constructor for toys.

Answer (score 1):

The stack overflow is happening in the Box() constructor. I'm not sure how does boost::assign work, but it looks like you're passing to it, as arguments, three temporary variables of type Toy. Constructed, as they are, on the stack.